# The average of two long odd/even numbers in Java without overflow

Tags: java

See the below code. I'm having difficulty finding a solution where the average of two **long** numbers in java do not result in overflow. The problem is when I add a odd integer with an even negative integer, example 
11  &  -12 results in mean of 1 for me using below. Is there an actual way of doing this without the use of a math program and using only primitive programming?

```
if (maximum > minimum) {
  this.max = maximum; this.min = minimum;
  this.counter = (minimum & maximum) + ((minimum ^ maximum) >> 1);
}
else if (minimum > maximum) {
  this.min = maximum; this.max = minimum;
  this.counter = (maximum & minimum) + ((maximum ^ minimum) >> 1);
}
else {
  this.max = maximum; this.min = minimum; counter = this.max;
}
```

Comment: In the case where one's positive and one's negative, you shouldn't have to worry about overflow. You can just sum them and divide by 2.

Comment: You can store the remainder of both values for the integer division by 2, then do this division, add the results and finally use the remainders to adjust value if necessary.

Comment: None of these solutions round **towards** zero if both integers are negative. Any suggestion for this case please?